# Downloading Bhuvan Panchayat 3.0 raw data

Tags: geospatial, india

I am trying to download **road** and other **spatial data** files used on the Bhuvan Panchayat 3.0 website (https://bhuvan-panchayat3.nrsc.gov.in/). Is there a way to either directly download the raw data from the website, or are there existing scripts that would allow me to scrape the data I need?